# terratest to test SQS

Tags: terraform, terratest

I am using terratests to test my terraform code.
so, my terraform code setup: SQS which is connected to Lambda and Lambda is the consumer of the SQS Message

so, I would like to test the whole flow, So thought of sending a dummy message to SQS and then read the message, using terratest however I can't read the message as the lambda already consumed it !!! I see cw logs for the lambda and it has consumed the message

can anyone suggest how to test this complete set of flow with terratest?

The testcode for SQS looks like this:

```
ack_queue_url := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "acknowledgment_queue_url")
    time_out_sec := 120
    test_message := fmt.Sprintf("terratest-test-message-%s", uniqueId)
    aws.SendMessageToQueue(t, awsRegion, ack_queue_url, test_message)
    response := aws.WaitForQueueMessage(t, awsRegion, ack_queue_url, time_out_sec)
    assert.NoError(t, response.Error)
    fmt.Println("###Message Body####:", response.MessageBody)
    aws.DeleteMessageFromQueue(t, awsRegion, ack_queue_url,  response.ReceiptHandle)
    delete_response := aws.WaitForQueueMessage(t, awsRegion, ack_queue_url, time_out_sec)
    assert.Error(t, delete_response.Error, aws.ReceiveMessageTimeout{QueueUrl: ack_queue_url, TimeoutSec: time_out_sec})
```

the output looks like this:

```
logger.go:66: "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue"
sqs.go:150: Sending message terratest-test-message-DkKAvt to queue https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue
sqs.go:170: Message id b9b0a000-1d71-4821-8659-21aebe33cdc0 sent to queue https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue
sqs.go:234: Waiting for message on https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue (0s)
sqs.go:234: Waiting for message on https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue(20s)
sqs.go:234: Waiting for message on https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue (40s)
sqs.go:234: Waiting for message on https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue (60s)
sqs.go:234: Waiting for message on https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue (80s)
sqs.go:234: Waiting for message on https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue (100s)
                Error Trace:    /Users/xxxx/Projects/dummy_test/terratest/complete_test.go:83
                Error:          Received unexpected error:
                                Failed to receive messages on https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue within 120 seconds
                Test:           complete_test
###Message Body####: 
sqs.go:125: Deleting message from queue https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234567/tst-queue()
    sqs.go:119: MissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter ReceiptHandle.
                status code: 400, request id: 4421cdfc-4326-5755-9623-91ca3414ed6f
```

Comment: I believe you would need to acceptance test the end behavior of the associated Lambda in this situation (perhaps retrieving and validating the CW logs with the AWS SDK like you are doing to send the message), unless you decoupled the resources.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I think I would have to do as you suggested. Thanks.